# Why doesn't this code render the time in addition to the date?

Tags: php, datetime, upload

This code renders the date (month, day, year) but not the time. It is being used on a php upload site.  I am grateful for any suggestions. Thank you.

```
<time datetime="<?= date( 'm-d-Y', strtotime( $file->added ) ) ?>"><?= date( 'm.d.Y', strtotime( $file->added ) ) ?>
```

Comment: You have forgotten to attach the code

Comment: Sheesh. Sorry, I couldn't figure out how to edit the question. Here is the code: <time datetime="<?= date( 'm-d-Y', strtotime( $file->added ) ) ?>"><?= date( 'm.d.Y', strtotime( $file->added ) ) ?>Elsewhere I have the time zone set to America New York. Thanks for looking at it.

Comment: Why do you think this code should render time additionally? Do you understand what `'m-d-Y'` and `'m.d.Y'` mean?

Comment: Month Day Year. I thought it would show the time because of strtotime. Please explain if you have the time. Thanks.

Comment: please read [`date()`](http://php.net/date) and [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime) functions documentation. Every time you don't know for sure what function does - **DON'T** even try to guess it by name, but read documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the request to output the time to parameter 1 of the date() function.

```
<time datetime="<?= date( 'm-d-Y H:i:s', strtotime( $file->added ) ) ?>"><?= date( 'm.d.Y H:i:s', strtotime( $file->added ) ) ?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works fine. I had tried <time datetime="<?= date( 'm-d-Y' 'h:i:s', strtotime( $file->added ) ) ?>"><?= date( 'm.d.Y' 'h:i:s', strtotime( $file->added ) ) ?> but it returned an error. I can see my mistakes now. Thanks everyone for advice and helping.